# Attribute name with symbols in XML with Python 3.6.2

Tags: xml, elementtree, python-3.6

I'm creating XML file with ElemenTree. In specification of receiving server attribute of node should be "name-1", but IDE receives me an error if I try to use it. Pls advice correct syntax for this attribute.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

Query = ET.Element("Query")
Command = ET.SubElement(Query, "Command)
Items = ET.SubElement(Command, "Items")
ET.SubElement(Items, "field2", name-1="Name").text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary to create the attribute. This prevents `name-1` from being interpreted as "`name` minus one".

```
ET.SubElement(Items, "field2", {"name-1": "Name"})
```